# Why does cvxpy return unbounded here?

Tags: linear-programming, cvxpy

I'm using cvxpy 0.4.9 and Python 2.7.14 and getting a surprising `unbounded` status from the example below.

Slight variations (say, drop the last constraint) correctly report `infeasible` status.

This happens in both Windows and Linux environments. Why?

```
import cvxpy
import numpy

def main():
    yld = numpy.array([[12.],[11.],[17.],[13.],[7.]])
    wts = cvxpy.Variable(5)
    obj = cvxpy.Maximize(yld.T * wts)

    cons = []
    cons.append(0.0 <= wts)
    cons.append(numpy.ones(5).T * wts == 1.0)
    cons.append(wts <= 2.5 * numpy.ones(5))
    cons.append(wts <= 0.25)
    cons.append(numpy.array([[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.],[1.]]).T * wts <= 0.0)
    cons.append(numpy.array([[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1 )
    cons.append(numpy.array([[0.],[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1 )
    cons.append(numpy.array([[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1 )
    cons.append(numpy.array([[0.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1 )

    prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, cons)

    prob.solve()
    print(prob.status)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I get `infeasible` with cvxpy 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

With cvxpy==1.0.10 I get `infeasible`.

The feasible set is clearly empty. Why?

- `numpy.array([[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.],[1.]]).T * wts <= 0.0` and `0.0 <= wts` imply that `wts[2] == wts[3] == wts[4] == 0`.
- `numpy.array([[0.],[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1`, `[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.]]).T * wts <= 0.1` and `0.0 <= wts` imply that `0 <= wts[0] == 0.1` and `0 <= wts[1] == 0.1`

Thus it it impossible to satisfy `numpy.ones(5).T * wts == 1.0` (sum of all elements of `wts` is 1).